# Select jsonb column with a subset of nested array based on id

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonb-array-elements

I have a jsonb column in the following format:

```
{
  "targets": {
    "01d7de90-57fd-4c4f-b7c9-3b956762fe25": {
      "id": "01d7de90-57fd-4c4f-b7c9-3b956762fe25",
      "name": "target1"
    },
    "0f43e1fe-132e-464b-8284-4a9947a70c1c": {
      "id": "0f43e1fe-132e-464b-8284-4a9947a70c1c",
      "name": "target2"
    }
  },
  "suggestions": [
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "foo",
          "code": "item1"
        }
      ],
      "groupId": 1
    },
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "bar",
          "code": "item2"
        }
      ],
      "groupId": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to return that same column but only with a subset of the `"items"` within `"suggestions"` subject to given item `"id"`.

For example, if I am interested in item with id `"foo"`, the return value should be:

```
{
  "targets": {
    "01d7de90-57fd-4c4f-b7c9-3b956762fe25": {
      "id": "01d7de90-57fd-4c4f-b7c9-3b956762fe25",
      "name": "target1"
    },
    "0f43e1fe-132e-464b-8284-4a9947a70c1c": {
      "id": "0f43e1fe-132e-464b-8284-4a9947a70c1c",
      "name": "target2"
    }
  },
  "suggestions": [
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "foo",
          "code": "item1"
        }
      ],
      "groupId": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried several things so far, including:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE jsonb_array_length(my_column->'suggestions') > 0
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(my_column->'suggestions') AS suggestions(items)
    WHERE items->'items' @> '[{"id": "foo"}]'
  );
```

and also

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(my_column->'suggestions') AS suggestions(suggestion)
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(suggestion->'items') AS items
    WHERE items->>'id' = 'foo'
  )
);
```

Unfortunately, none of these worked. I've also tried to figure out how can I solve this with `jsonb_path_query_array` but the column is way too nested for me to figure out the appropriate query path.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, first recreate the items array using `jsonb_agg`, then replace the jsonb column using `jsonb_set`:

```
select my_column, jsonb_set(my_column::jsonb, '{suggestions}', items_updated::jsonb) edited
from (
  select my_column, jsonb_agg(items) as items_updated
  from my_table,
     jsonb_array_elements(my_column->'suggestions') as items
  where value->'items' @> '[{"id": "foo"}]'
  group by my_column
) as s
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/eZvIPOOr)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to query your JSON in the path for suggestions and replace the result into the JSON tree like:

```
select my_column, 
jsonb_set(my_column, '{suggestions}', sel_item) my_result
from (  select my_column,  
        jsonb_path_query_array(my_column, 
        '$.suggestions[*] ? (@.items.id == "foo")') sel_item
        from my_table 
) as t;
```

[Working sample here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qvmJUXk3ohDW347cQ4odno/3)